# How to pass binding with ERB.result_with_hash

Tags: ruby, erb

I was previously only passing binding like this

```rb
class GenerateFiles
  def is_xyz(abcd)
    return abcd
  end

  def render_template(fileName, binding)
    template = ERB.new File.read("templates/#{fileName}"), nil, "%"
    template.result(binding)
  end
end
```

However, I had some other data I wanted to pass (called `args`, which is a Hash), so I made changes to render with the new `result_with_hash(args)` function.

With `result_with_hash`, my templates only have access to the variables in `args`, and not `binding`.

How can I pass both?

I've tried

`ERB.new(template).result(OpenStruct.new(args).instance_eval { binding })`

but I was getting an error because the template couldn't get access to a function `is_xyz` in the scope through binding. I used it in the template like `<%= is_xyz abcd %>`, and this worked fine before when I was only passing binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if you need to use both the `args` and `binding`, you need to populate keys/values of your `args` into the binding object.

```ruby
# To avoid polluting your current binding, copy to a new one
b_clone = binding.clone
args.each { |k, v| b_clone.local_variable_set(k,v) }
ERB.new(template).result(b_clone)
```

So you can use both methods in your binding and keys/values in args as variables